# How to edit Word Art text in .docx document

Tags: python

Using the code below am successfully able to dynamically edit a word document and replace some of the words which I want. How can I add support so that it can also find Word Art text since it seems to be ignoring that.

```
import re
from docx import Document

def docx_replace_regex(doc_obj, regex , replace):

  for p in doc_obj.paragraphs:
        if regex.search(p.text):
            inline = p.runs
            # Loop added to work with runs (strings with same style)
            for i in range(len(inline)):
                if regex.search(inline[i].text):
                    text = regex.sub(replace, inline[i].text)
                    inline[i].text = text

    for table in doc_obj.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                docx_replace_regex(cell, regex , replace)
filename = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\CAR PRIVATE7.docx"

regex1 = re.compile(r"OLD")
replace1 = r"JOHN KAITA"

regex2 = re.compile(r"KBQ648E")
replace2 = r"KLM789J"

doc = Document(filename)

docx_replace_regex(doc, regex1 , replace1)
docx_replace_regex(doc, regex2 , replace2)


doc.save('C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\CAR PRIVATE8.docx')
```